# What causes jQuery "$(...) is null" on some pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, null

I have some javascript which controls a hidden div. Now it works on most pages, but on other pages with other javascripts it is not working... Is my js written poorly?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#user-dropdown-toggle").live ('click', function() {
    $("#left-user-bar").addClass("open");
    $("#user-dropdown-toggle").addClass("league-judgement");
    $("body").addClass("league-judgement");
});
$(".league-judgement").live('click', function() {
  $("#left-user-bar").removeClass("open");
  $("#user-dropdown-toggle").removeClass("league-judgement");
  $("body").removeClass("league-judgement");
});
});
```

Firefox is reporting the following in the error console:

Timestamp: 4/18/2012 9:08:21 PM
Error: $("#user-dropdown-toggle") is null

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The `$` function *in jQuery* will never return `null`.** So it is likely it is a different *non-jQuery* `$` in use. (Is there any ASP.NET stuff or prototype.js or other library being used? A custom `$` function declared later on?)

I know that `$` is itself *not* `null` because the exception would be different, such as: "$ is not a function". In this case the browser is saying *the result of* the expression (`$(...)`) is `null`, which leads me to the above conclusion.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function($) { // <-- note $ there
   ...
});
```

Or, better yet, as it only relies on `window.jQuery` and not `window.$`:

```
jQuery(function($) { // <-- note $ there
   ...
});
```

And, if that works, then it is that `$` is being clobbered before the "ready" event (but after `$(...).ready`). Of course, it is possible (but not very likely) that the `$` is *already* not jQuery at this point...

To see if `$` is jQuery (use the Web Developer Console or Firebug):

- `$ === jQuery` should generally be true, but it might not be depending on `noConflict` and such
- `$.fn.jquery` and `$().jquery` should both result in the jQuery version as a string
- `$` (just specifying the function on the console will "display the source")

As an aside, I would *indent* the function body (e.g. in the "ready" callback) to see where it start/ends more clearly.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I never knew I could do some of that with Firebug. The javascript that is causing mine to break is located here: http://www.leaguejudgement.com/forum/public/min/index.php?ipbv=31005&g=js and as you can see, it's a lot. I am not a js expert, so I might try and find a smaller js script to convert bbcode in my form.

Comment: @PaulELI There is this suspicious thing: `function $(element){...}` in that code, which overrides `$` (I think it's in the `window` scope, but hard to tell with the minimization) and looks like it could be related to the use of the "Prototype.js" library. Anyway, does the `function($)` approach do the trick? If not, does using `jQuery` and not `$` fix the issue? This should be quite "safe": `jQuery(function ($) { /* original stuff that uses $ */ })` and generally immune to other libraries.

Comment: Ok I got it to work with what you said... I didn't comprehend your initial post well and was taking it a different direction, but your original post makes a lot of sense now. Thanks a ton, it fixed it. This is good to know for future js endeavors. The prototype or whatever library the Rich Text editor is using seems to be a culprit in some more issues, so I will probably go ahead and replace it.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is to make sure jQuery is included on all pages. I assume this is the case since it did not have issue with the $(document).ready bit but you never know.

Take a look at this post for more info: [jQuery $("#field") is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777062/jquery-field-is-null)

Answer (score 0):

You should add your jquery script/include line.

Also you mention "other JS" on same page.. you should check that it is not loading a different version of JQuery than the one you are using -- overriding your imported version of your library.....