# jQuery TypeError: $(...) is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

The concept here is that i want to make a "Recently Added" type of function that will read the last four rows of a csv file and write them onto an HTML page. I am using [this](http://www.html5webtemplates.co.uk/templates/simple_slide_light/index.html) HTML5 template.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>My Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"     />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"    type="textjavascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="style/accordian.pack.js"></script>        
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="style/globe.gif"/>
</head>

<body onload="new Accordian('basic-accordian',5,'header_highlight');">
     
  <!-- Logo -->
  <div id="logo"><h1>My Logo</h1></div>
  <div id="basic-accordian" >

  <!-- Home Dropdown -->
    <div id="test-header" class="accordion_headings header_highlight">Home</div>
    <div id="test-content">
      <div class="accordion_child">
        <p>The csv values should be placed under this text...</p>
    
         <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">             
            $(document).ready(function () {
              $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "db_data.csv",
              dataType: "text",
              success: function(data) {processData(data);}
              });

            // process the data from the data file
            function processData(data) {
              var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);

              var headings = lines[0].split(','); 
              document.write("<h3>Recently Uploaded<h3><br>")
              for (var j=lines.length-2; j>(lines.length-1)-5; j--) { //only load values from the last 4 rows
              var values = lines[j].split(','); 
                 
                 var desc = values[0];
                 var uploader = values[1];
                 var url = values[15];
                console.log(desc + " " + uploader + " " + url)
                document.write(desc + " " + uploader + " " + url)
              }
            }
            });
          </script>     
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I keep getting the $(...) is null error. When i removed the template and wrote some basic HTML just for debugging it worked! The thing is that the template needs to stay and i have no idea why it does not work with it.

Here's the code that works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">          


        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "db_data.csv",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {processData(data);}
            });

        //process the data from the data file
        function processData(data) {
            var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);

            var headings = lines[0].split(',');
            document.write("<h3>Recently Uploaded<h3><br>")
            for (var j=lines.length-2; j>(lines.length-1)-5; j--) {
            var values = lines[j].split(','); 
               
               var desc = values[0];
               var uploader = values[1];
               var url = values[15];
                console.log(desc + " " + uploader + " " + url)
                document.write(desc + " " + uploader + " " + url)
            }
        }
    });         
    </script>
</body>
```

If you want, make a dummy csv with >=15 columns and >=5 rows named db_data.csv and try it out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221159/what-causes-jquery-is-null-on-some-pages

Comment: use the developer console in firefox/chrome to see what line's causing the error & the exact error message

Comment: don't use `document.write` after page loads...wipes out the page

Comment: @charlietfl I know it's off topic but is it possible to provide me with the alternative to document.write (with code)?

Comment: Use jQuery insertion methods like `html()` ..`append()` etc. Take an hour or two and go through various jQuery methods in the api and see examples. A uick walk through various parts of it first so you get a feel for what it can do .... then keep the api bookmarked and refer back to often

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this isn't a typo when you posted your snippet, the issue is probably here:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="textjavascript"></script>
```

This should be **"text/javascript"**, not **"textjavascript"**.