# jquery uikit modal not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, uikit

I am using UIkit to able users to edit there posts(ideas).

**HTML**:

```
<button class="editModal uk-icon-edit uk-button uk-button-link"></button>
<div id="newIdea" class="uk-modal">
     <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-dialog-large">
         <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
         ....
     </div>
 </div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).on('click','.editModal',function() {
    var modal = UIkit.modal("#newIdea");

    if ( modal.isActive() ) {
        modal.hide();
    } else {
        modal.show();
    }
  });
```

---

When you click the button nothing happens.

I am using this [documentation](http://getuikit.com/docs/modal.html).

Comment: please check your uikit and jquery library path.

Comment: I think my problem is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221159/what-causes-jquery-is-null-on-some-pages

Comment: open console log in firebug and show the error

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203125/typeerror-is-null-error-in-firebug-but-code-works-on-jsfiddle) may help you