# jQuery custom function throwing error when no selected elements exist

Tags: jquery

I have a custom function which disables text selection for the selected elements. The custom function is structured like this:

```
$.fn.DisableTextSelect = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    // do things to 'this' element
    // ...
  });
};
```

I call it like this, for example:

```
$("label").DisableTextSelect();
```

Problem is, when there are no elements to operate on, instead of just doing nothing, an error is thrown, which Firebug shows as `$("label") is null` pointing to the line above.

[image]

Have I written the function incorrectly? If there are no elements found, I thought it would simply return; ie. not perform the each() loop.

Comment: Well you are calling a function on a null object? Is this not like null.anyFunctionEver() ?? I do not know how jquery wraps null, but this looks like the standard "you cannot do things with null" error.

Comment: I made a fiddle with your exact code and I'm not having the same problem. Is the page including jQuery correctly? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mstauffer/fFcsk/ Edit: If jQuery wasn't included correctly, it would say '$ is not defined', so that's not it...

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777062/jquery-field-is-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out one of the devs had isolated the code but not passed the jQuery object.

This

```
(function() {
  lots of code...
})();
```

Should have been this:

```
(function($) {
  lots of code...
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks for the responses guys!