# jQuery - standard code yet doesn't seem to be working? [$ selector returning Null]

Tags: jquery

I want to pass data by AJAX to perform a lookup of a correct HTML class, then perform a jQuery action on elements of that class upon completion.

This is what I have so far, simplified:

```
<span class="data_type_1">some data here</span>
<span class="data_type_2">some data here</span>
<span class="data_type_1">some data here</span>
<a href="javascript:removedata(57);">click to remove all data with id=57</a>

function removedata(id_to_remove) {
    var url = "/my.php";     
                // Calling with 'id=57' returns class_to_remove ='data_type_1'
    jQuery.ajax(
        url,
        {
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id: id_to_remove,
                },
            complete: remove_callback
        });
}    

function remove_callback(transport) {
    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(transport.responseText);
    var class_to_remove = response.class_to_remove;

    alert ('debug point 1:  class_to_remove = ' + class_to_remove);
    $("span." + class_to_remove ).html('DATA TEMPORARILY REMOVED');
    alert ('debug point 2:  removal done');
}
```

I've tested it to the point that the ajax call works, the callback is happening, the data at debug point #1 is correct (class_to_remove = 'data_type_1')... and then nothing more happens, I can't get the action to execute, but there's no error message either.

The code seems basic and the syntax for the desired action is shown on dozens of web pages; what am I missing?

**Update:**

Something's going wrong with the function $('.CLASS_NAME') - when I add a further debug statement, `alert($('.data_type_1'));` the response is `Null` even though I can look at the page source and see plenty of elements with that class name.

Comment: R u trying to remove the content in span? could have used $('.'+ class_to_remove ).html('')

Comment: Is there any script error?

Comment: Do you receive alert from `debug point 2`?

Comment: Hi! Do you see any error on console?

Comment: Code seems like working fine. Try to print your transport.responseText and make sure that its returning correct class.

Comment: **@CodingAnt, @Mutant, @Felix, @Littm** - no console errors seen and  class name returned is correct. Following these comments, the issue seems to be that `$('.data_type_1')` is returning Null, which seems wrong. When I manually test the $(...) snippet, using `alert($('.data_type_1'));` I get Null instead of a non-Null return value of some kind. But then I look at the page source and there are dozens of elements with `class="data_type_1"` and doesn't seem to be a typo either. I've checked by adding `alert($('.SOME_OTHER_CLASS'))` for some other class in the HTML and that returned Null too.

Comment: @Stilez - In that case I find it hard to believe that there is no error. I tried your quick snippet on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jpatel/uCzFV/1/ and if the classname is correct it seems to be responding fine.

Comment: @Mutant - your fiddle link didn't work (clicking the link bottom right did nothing), which made me suspicious. The dev console (F12) said `"SCRIPT5: Access is denied | 
display, line 1 character 1 | {"error": "Please use POST request"}"`. Google says this might relate to IE 10 protected mode, but it seems odd for jQuery to fail, as it's so careful on testing and widely used. Maybe I have used your fiddle wrongly somehow?? In my original attempts, AJAX worked but '$('.CLASSNAME')' wasn't (returned Null). I'm still confused but wondering if this hints at a browser mis-config cause to fix?

Comment: Can you try in any other browser? just to be sure.

Comment: @Mutant - Doesn't seem to be browser after all?? Firefox web console: `document.getElementsByClassName('testclass')` evaluates to a collection and `document.getElementsByClassName('testclass')[0].innerHTML` and `document.querySelectorAll('testclass')[0].innerHTML` both evaluate to expected innerHTML text, but `$('.testclass')` still evaluates to Null? Manually entered into console one after the other

Comment: @Stilez - It might be too late to ask, but again just want to confirm that you are loading jquery correctly, and the function code you have it in $(document).ready(function(){....}); block.

Comment: @Mutant Following a search for jquery selector null (etc), I found [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777062/jquery-field-is-null) suggested using jQuery(...) rather than $(...) which works, so I have a workaround  - but now I know that, any idea why? And how to fix it?

Comment: You can move your code in following block jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
}); so it will make sure that the $ in that scope is jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not working because you are trying to parse the json response, which in your case is not required.

You have mentioned the ajax call data type as `json` in the call. So the returned response will be already a parsed javascript object.

Comment: I'm keeping the response type as JSON in case I want to expand in future to add other data, like a more specific text rather than static text.  It isn't the problem - the first debug alert shows the right value is being returns/used. Somehow $('.data_type_1') itself is unexpectedly evaluating to Null - checked and not a typo - which seems incorrect, and that seems to be the issue (see update) ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in some circumstances the usual syntax one sees, `$(...)` can return Null unexpectedly, where replacing "$" by "jQuery" to give the identically-performing `jQuery(...)` does returns the expected values. This either gives a workaround, or a starting point to find why it's happening and fix it.

Other relevant issues raised in the thread include checking it's not Protected Mode (Internet Explorer) or other browser issue (via another browser), testing code manually in a Developer panel or console, and using functionality @Mutant excellently describes in the Comments.

**@Mutant** - Thanks for all the help, which eliminated issues and suggested how to track it down!!