# jQuery error even though jQuery is included

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this in my header:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('contextmenu', 'img', function(e){ return false; }); 
});
</script>
```

However, I'm getting this error, pointing to the line that uses the `$`:

```
Error: TypeError: $(...) is null
```

The code is supposed to prevent right clicks on images (I know it's a futile effort, please skip that discussion if you can).

Anyway, the code used to work, but now I opened the page and it no longer does.

Any ideas what may be the cause?

I've tried removing the lightbox include just to make sure it's not causing any issues, and it's not.

Comment: is this on a server?

Comment: Sorry, what? Is it on a server? Yes, it's been on a dedicated server this whole time.

Comment: `$('body')` can't possibly be null. Are you sure it doesn't appear inside the lightbox or any other script?

Comment: My psychic powers tell me one of the recent changes that went into that code was the inclusion of the [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/learn/) library, whose `$()` function will overwrite jQuery's unless you take special steps and, contrary to jQuery's, *can* return `null`.

Comment: what do you get if you type `$` in the browser console?

Comment: is this your code or is it something like this? something like this isn't very helpful

Comment: That is the code, I just took out the CSS includes for clarity. I am fixing this for a friend, so I'm not sure what changes were made recently, but I don't see Prototype anywhere.

Comment: What does you console say, do you get any errors when loading the jQuery file (networking)?

Comment: @jovan, it must occur later in the document, because the call to `$(document)` succeeds, so jQuery is still in charge at that time. By the time the `ready` handler runs, though, `$()` is no longer the jQuery function/constructor.

Comment: try making the include with http:// instead of //

Comment: type $ in the console (F12 in Chrome) and it should say where $ is defined, if it is not declared in jQuery then there is a problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L3tf078f/ are you shure that it's not an lightbox problem?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yup, there was a Prototype include somewhere in the file, inside a PHP include. For some reason. If you wanna put your educated guess in an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Have a look  @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777062/jquery-field-is-null

Comment: @jovan, this problem has already been discussed here, so I tried to find an appropriate duplicate instead. Hope you don't mind.